# send form data and opens get div with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, get

I like to open search results in a form in a div of the page via Ajax. I'm trying this:

```
    <form id="buscar" method="GET" >

     <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="busqueda"/> 
    <input type="submit" class="busca" value="Buscar" />
    </FORM>


<div id="derecho"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#buscar').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/buscador/busqueda.php",
            data:"busqueda="+busqueda,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#derecho').html(data);
            }
        })        
        return false;
    }); 

    });
```

It turns out that in this way it does not work, see if you can help me out. Is there a mistake with Ajax? In the html form?

I need to send GET to the search know what they have to find in the database.

And I would like the contents of the search appear in the #derecho div.

To see if I can say I have bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close to the solution. You just have to get the value of the input via using form or with jQuery;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#buscar').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/buscador/busqueda.php",
            data:"busqueda=" + this.busqueda.value, // Here "this" refers to your form object.
            success: function(data) {
                $('#derecho').html(data);
            }
        })        
        return false;
    });
});
```